# Getting atomic time in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the atomic time in php.

```
 $fp = @fsockopen( "time-a.nist.gov", 37, $errno, $errstr, 10 );
if ( !$fp )
{
    echo $errstr;
}
else
{ 
    fputs($fp, "\n"); 
    $time_info = fread($fp, 49);
    fclose($fp);
}
/*** create the timestamp ***/
$atomic_time = (abs(hexdec('7fffffff') - hexdec(bin2hex($time_info)) - hexdec('7fffffff')) - 2208988800); 
echo $errstr;`
```

But I only get connection timeouts with every server I try to connect.

I have tested different server, but all with the same error. Now I am wondering what is wrong with my code.

Is there a better way to ensure atomic time? My boss doesnt want us to use servertime.

Comment: Hopefully you realize anyway, that by the time you receive the atomic time, it's no longer accurate.

Comment: @zneak: Adding half the duration of the call is a not-horrible compensation.

Comment: Hosting does not block outbound connections?

Comment: You're hiding errors. Remove the error supression operator (`@`) and you might get a useful error. Might be a faulty DNS?

Comment: I've tested this code, it works fine. You only need to replace in the last line "echo $errstr" at "echo $atomic _time". Probably a problem with the ban on outgoing connections, or something else.

Comment: using time-c.nist.gov which is labeled available still gives me unction.fsockopen</a>]: unable to connect to time-c.nist.gov:37 (Connection timed out)

Comment: Why not just use [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) to synchronise the server time, and _then_ use the server time?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, my boss doesnt want us to use servertime, even synchronised servertime.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but bosses are seldom correct in their manner of approach. That's why they are bosses and not coders. ;)